# How can Stored Procedures and Triggers be Automatically Loaded When MySQL Starts

Tags: mysql

Is there any straightforward method of doing as the questions asks?

We are using MySQL 5.5 & Linux.

Comment: [mysqld] init_file=blah.sql in the options file

Answer (score 1):

Use a cron task. 
Here are some examples for mysql

http://dbperf.wordpress.com/2010/04/05/scheduling-a-mysql-stored-procedure-using-a-linux-cron-job-and-mysql-events/

Add at boot
http://jonathonhill.net/2009-08-18/easy-startup-scripts-using-crontab/

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to consider

Stored Procedures/Functions are physically stored in mysql.proc as a MyISAM table

```
mysql> show create table `mysql.proc`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: proc
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `proc` (
  `db` char(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name` char(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `type` enum('FUNCTION','PROCEDURE') NOT NULL,
  `specific_name` char(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `language` enum('SQL') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'SQL',
  `sql_data_access` enum('CONTAINS_SQL','NO_SQL','READS_SQL_DATA','MODIFIES_SQL_DATA') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'CONTAINS_SQL',
  `is_deterministic` enum('YES','NO') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NO',
  `security_type` enum('INVOKER','DEFINER') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'DEFINER',
  `param_list` blob NOT NULL,
  `returns` longblob NOT NULL,
  `body` longblob NOT NULL,
  `definer` char(77) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `sql_mode` set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','NOT_USED','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_ALL_TABLES','NO_ZERO_IN_DATE','NO_ZERO_DATE','INVALID_DATES','ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO','TRADITIONAL','NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER','HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE','NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION','PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH') NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `character_set_client` char(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `collation_connection` char(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `db_collation` char(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `body_utf8` longblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`db`,`name`,`type`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Stored Procedures'
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Stored Procedures/Functions are physically and logically stored in `information_schema.routines` as a temporary MyISAM table:

```
mysql> show create table information_schema.routines\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: ROUTINES
Create Table: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `ROUTINES` (
  `SPECIFIC_NAME` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ROUTINE_CATALOG` varchar(512) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ROUTINE_SCHEMA` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ROUTINE_NAME` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ROUTINE_TYPE` varchar(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `DATA_TYPE` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` int(21) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH` int(21) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NUMERIC_PRECISION` int(21) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NUMERIC_SCALE` int(21) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CHARACTER_SET_NAME` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COLLATION_NAME` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DTD_IDENTIFIER` longtext,
  `ROUTINE_BODY` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ROUTINE_DEFINITION` longtext,
  `EXTERNAL_NAME` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EXTERNAL_LANGUAGE` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PARAMETER_STYLE` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `IS_DETERMINISTIC` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `SQL_DATA_ACCESS` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `SQL_PATH` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SECURITY_TYPE` varchar(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CREATED` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `LAST_ALTERED` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `SQL_MODE` varchar(8192) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ROUTINE_COMMENT` longtext NOT NULL,
  `DEFINER` varchar(77) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `COLLATION_CONNECTION` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `DATABASE_COLLATION` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In reality, there absolutely no need to read all Stored Procedures/Functions as mysqld has already done this. In fact, once you shutdown mysql,

- `information_schema.routines` will get dropped
- `mysql.proc` remains in existence

What mysqld actually does on startup is populate `information_schema.routines` from `mysql.proc`.

Triggers are similarly stored. Here is `information_schema.triggers`

```
mysql> show create table information_schema.triggers\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: TRIGGERS
Create Table: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `TRIGGERS` (
  `TRIGGER_CATALOG` varchar(512) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `TRIGGER_SCHEMA` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `TRIGGER_NAME` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `EVENT_MANIPULATION` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `EVENT_OBJECT_CATALOG` varchar(512) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ACTION_ORDER` bigint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ACTION_CONDITION` longtext,
  `ACTION_STATEMENT` longtext NOT NULL,
  `ACTION_ORIENTATION` varchar(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ACTION_TIMING` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ACTION_REFERENCE_OLD_TABLE` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ACTION_REFERENCE_NEW_TABLE` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ACTION_REFERENCE_OLD_ROW` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ACTION_REFERENCE_NEW_ROW` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CREATED` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `SQL_MODE` varchar(8192) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `DEFINER` varchar(77) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `COLLATION_CONNECTION` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `DATABASE_COLLATION` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The physical manifestation of triggers resides in database folder of the table that own the trigger. Trigger code resides in a file with the extension `.TRG`.

For example, for a given MyISAM table mydb.mytable that has triggers, you will have

- `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.frm`
- `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.MYD`
- `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.MYI`
- `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.TRG`

Although you may not get good results, if you still want to experiment with reading triggers and stored procedures immediately after startup:

STEP 01) Create a script to read those tables

```
cd /var/lib/mysql
echo "SELECT * FROM information_schema.routines;"  > init_file.sql
echo "SELECT * FROM information_schema.triggers;" >> init_file.sql
```

STEP 02) Add this line to `/etc/my.cnf`

```
init-file=/var/lib/mysql/init_file.sql
```

STEP 03) No need to restart mysqld. Just run the script by hand

```
mysql> source /var/lib/mysql/init_file.sql
```

That's all I can suggest. Since routines and triggers are preloaded, this suggestion may not yield any additional performance. You can try anyway and please with your findings.